# Не работает медиа-запрос при импорте

Tags: css, media

Господа, столкнулся с интересной ситуацией. 
При попытке задать медиа-запрос, он игнорируется браузером (проверено в хроме и мозилле) при выполнении своего условия.
 [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

meta viewport в head прописан, медиазапрос пишется после остального css кода (все собирается в конечном файле style.sass с помощью импорта, потом генерируется в .min.css. Последний открывал, медиа также прописано в конце. Где тут собакен закопан?)

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score 2):

вне медиазапроса у вас прописана вложенность .menu .menu_item, а в медиазапросе прописан просто класс .menu_item, возможно вложенность перебивает стили медиазапроса. попробуйте так

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1200px)
.menu .menu_item {
  padding-right: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Действительно, в этом и оказалась причина. Спасибо!